# How can I access an individual element from JSON file via Angular4 HTTP Get?

Tags: angular, http, get, rxjs

My JSON file is structured as follows:

```
 [
    {id: 1,
     title: "First Element"
    },
    {id: 2,
     title: "Second Element"
    },
    {id: 3,
     title: "Third Element"
    }
 ]
```

I have been able to successfully retrieve the entire JSON array (file) by calling something like

Component.ts:

```
this.dataService.getAll()
    .subscribe(
        (data: Book[]) => this.myData = data,
        (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
```

Service.ts

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiURL)
```

where apiURL is the path to a local json file in my library. If possible, how can I get ONLY the first element with id 1 and title "First element"?

I've been trying this:

```
getBookById(title: String) Observable<Book> {
    return this.http.get<Book>(this.apiURL + `/${title}`)
```

With the same component.ts method except using Book rather than Book[]. But it fails with HTTPGet error saying it can't find it. It makes sense because I feel like I am missing a field in between the title and the URL (for accessing or parsing through each element), but is there some syntax for this I'm missing or something else? Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Does the backend that you are calling allow retrieving a book by title? If the backend does not understand the URL you are passing it, it will generate a not found error.

Comment: So currently the JSON data is stored in a local file within my Angular project directory, such as '../../assets/data/topics.json' and that's what the apiURL refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reread your post (maybe you updated it) and it specifically says you are reading a JSON file. So I assume that file is local on the client.

If so, there is no mechanism to retrieve a single element from a JSON file with http. You can only read the entire file.

You *can* then filter the results to only the one you want or find the one in the array.

For example, here is one of mine:

```
products.find(p => p.productId === id))
```

This finds the particular product by id where `products` is my retrieved array.